# Read text file into class variable - c++

Tags: c++, class, fstream, getline, atoi

So... I tried to make an in-game shop system that reads player's account balance out of .txt file, but I've encountered this realy weird problem

So. This int works just fine. It reads data out of file, converts string to a numeric value, and prints it out.

```
int main() {
    int money;
    string cash;

    ifstream playerdata;
    playerdata.open("player.txt");
    if (playerdata.is_open()) {
    getline(playerdata,cash);
    money = atoi(cash.c_str());
    } else cout<<"error";
    return money;
}
```

While this one doesn't. It always prints out that cash is equal to 0.

```
class Player {
    int money ;
    string cash;
    public:
        GetMoney();
        int PrintMoney() {return atoi(cash.c_str());};

};

Player::GetMoney(){
    int money;
    string cash;

    ifstream playerdata;
    playerdata.open("player.txt");
    if (playerdata.is_open()) {
    getline(playerdata,cash);
    money = atoi(cash.c_str());
    playerdata.close();
    } else cout<<"error";
}

int main() {

    Player a;
    cout<<"Your Money: "<<a.PrintMoney()<<"$";  
};
```

Comment: You have two variables called `cash` - you only want one; the member variable.

Comment: still prining out the same thing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic in `main` is as follows:

- Create `a` of type `Player`.
- Call `PrintMoney()` function on `a`.

Your implementation of the `PrintMoney` function does not call the `GetMoney` function. In this case, `cash` is an empty string. Calling `c_str` on this empty string will result in an empty value being passed to `atoi`, which will return a 0.

According to the domain this appears correct. The Player doesn't yet have any money. Perhaps after declaring `a` you need to call `a.GetMoney()`, however there are other problems with your code that mean this won't quite work.

The `money` and `cash` variables in the `GetMoney` function will *override* the variables in the `Player` class. You should remove these.

Comment: Thanks. Solved. All the problem was caused because of `GetMoney`not beeing called.